# Angular directive and controller 2 way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Error: Expression 'undefined' used with directive is non-assignable
```

I'm getting the above error when trying to change a controller scope variable from my directive. Directive:

```
<mydir selUser="selectedUser"></mydir>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selectedUser = {};

    $scope.$watch('selectedUser', function() {
      console.log('user changed');
    });

});
```

And finally my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('mydir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/mydir/mydir.html',
      scope: {
        selUser: '='
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.changeUser = function(user) {
          console.log('user: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
          scope.selUser = user;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

As you can see, I am trying to change the selected user in the parent (controller) scope on the click of a button. But then the click happens, the error is thrown.

I have seen several combinations of how to define the scope in the directive and on the html declaring the directive but none of these seemed to work. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Your attribute should be `sel-user`, not `selUser`, ie `<mydir sel-user="selectedUser"></mydir>`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Complementing: take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive